# elsif with nextboolean for pictures

Tags: java, if-statement, random, boolean, bufferedimage

i am making a game with cactus pictures but when i do my code if its trying to switch between pictures it will stops and will freeze on that point the else if it does not work i also use bufferedimage for the pictures
my code:

```
   package objectgame;

import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import util.Resource;

public class EnemiesManager {
    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private Random random;
    
    private BufferedImage imagecactus1, imagecactus2, imagecactus3 ;
    
    public EnemiesManager() {
        enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
        imagecactus1 = Resource.getResourceImage("data/cactus1.png");
        imagecactus2 = Resource.getResourceImage("data/cactus2.png");
        imagecactus3 = Resource.getResourceImage("data/cactus3.png");
        random = new Random();
        
        enemies.add(getRandomCactus());
        random = new Random();
    }
    
    public void update() {
        for(Enemy e: enemies) {
            e.update();
        }
        Enemy firstEnemy = enemies.get(0);
        if(firstEnemy.isOutOfScreen()) {
            enemies.remove(firstEnemy);
            enemies.add(getRandomCactus());
        }
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for(Enemy e: enemies) {
            e.draw(g);
        }
    }
    private Cactus getRandomCactus() {
        Cactus cactus;
        cactus = new Cactus();
        cactus.setX(600);
        if(random.nextBoolean()) {
            cactus.setImage(imagecactus1);
        } 
        else{
            cactus.setImage(imagecactus2);
    }
        return cactus;
    }
}
```

new class

```
package objectgame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import util.Resource;

public class Cactus extends Enemy{
    
    private BufferedImage image;
    private int posX, posY;
    private Rectangle rect;
    
    public Cactus() {
        image = Resource.getResourceImage("data/cactus1.png");
        posX = 200;
        posY = 83;
        rect = new Rectangle();
    }
    
    public void update() {
        posX -= 3;
        rect.x = posX;
        rect.y = posY;
        rect.width = image.getWidth();
        rect.height = image.getHeight();
    }
    @Override
    public Rectangle getBound() {
        return rect;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, posX, posY, null);
    }
    
    public void setX(int x) {
        posX = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        posY = y;
    }
    public void setImage(BufferedImage images) {
        this.image = images;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isOutOfScreen() {
        return (posX + image.getWidth() < 0);
    }
}
```

what is the problem this is the code from the anamation manager and the details from the picture. I have tried many tutorials but none where working correct always slightly off the purpose for the random bool. I use eclipse so I don't get any errors specific to the location where the error happens. I also did use debugger but non are working. So I really need your guys help.

Comment: I think you should explain in more detail what do you mean by "it will stop and nothing works" - does it crash? does the result differ for what you were hoping for? 
Showing the context where the variable "random" is declared can also help.
best of luck.

Comment: yes it does crash when the new cactus come the game will freeze

Comment: do you want the whole class for the cactus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean approach is as follows:

```
private Cactus getRandomCactus() {
    Cactus cactus = new Cactus();
    cactus.setX(600);
    BufferedImage [] images = {imagecactus1, imagecactus2, imagecactus3};
    cactus.setImage(images[random.nextInt(3)]);
    return cactus;
}
```

**Note:** `random.nextInt(3)` returns an `int` from 0 to 2 i.e. either 0 or 1 or 2.

Comment: i use BufferedImage when i try this i does not work

Comment: @kajvans - The solution is still valid. Just replace `Image` with `BufferedImage`. I've updated my answer. Try now and feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: if i try now the game starts with freezing

Comment: There seems to be a problem somewhere else in your code. In order to help you further, I need to see your complete code.

Comment: how can i send it beacause it is in more than one class, also it is not fully done

Comment: You can edit the question and post whatever code you have.

Comment: it is not in one page i use eclipse and i have many folders where you can not see the code of so is gets than one mess is it good if i upload and that i give you the url or something else but from wich site

Comment: if i try that some lines get outside the code area and someothers get inside the code lines

Comment: i get the error: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. but i did use CTRL+K

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: it is done this is the code for the animation it are 2 classes if you need the main code you must ask

Comment: Your code looks good. Do you mean it working well with `cactus1` and `cactus2` but freezes when you introduce `cactus3`?

Comment: yes cactus 1 and 2 work but on the moment the program spawn 3 the game freeezs

Comment: My guess is that either image number 3 is broken or you have a memory issue. Try setting only that image for the cactus and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons you could be running into issues, the main one being the fact that you're called Random.nextBoolean() multiple times. When you do that, it gives you a new value each time. You'd want to set a variable equal to Random.nextBoolean().

Also, since you appear to be choosing between three different images, rather than two. For this, I recommend you use Random.nextInt instead:

```
private Cactus getRandomCactus() {
Cactus cactus;
cactus = new Cactus();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(0, 3); // this only called random.nextInt once, and gives me a random number between 0 and 2
cactus.setX(600);
if(randomInt == 0) {
    cactus.setImage(imagecactus1);
} 
else if (randomInt == 1) {
    cactus.setImage(imagecactus2);
}
else {
    cactus.setImage(imagecactus3);
}
    return cactus;
}
```

Comment: if i try your code i get many erros the game does not work he sets the pictures together and than nothing moves

Answer (score 0):

the problem what that there where 2 files called cactus3.png and also there was one space to much. thanks for thinking with me .